Grouping Data After an Event
I am trying to group individuals the first years after changing employers to see if their wages increased. The a sample of the data is below.
mpi   result    obs wages0     employer
<chr>   <chr>   <int>           <chr>
persona stayer  5   9153        employera
persona stayer  6   10713       employera
persona stayer  7   9895        employera
personb stayer  8   11416       employerb
personb stayer  0   5258        employerb
personb stayer  1   4970        employerb
personc mover   5   15000       employerc
personc stayer  6   12923       employerc
personc stayer  7   26269       employerc
personc stayer  8   28538       employerc
personc stayer  9   24761       employerc
personc stayer  10  25661       employerc

How to do I subset the data so that I only have personc after they have changed employers, and only for the first four observations after changing jobs. Please see below for the desired output.
mpi    result   obs wages0     employer
<chr>   <chr>   <int>           <chr>
personc mover   5   15000       employerc
personc stayer  6   12923       employerc
personc stayer  7   26269       employerc
personc stayer  8   28538       employerc
personc stayer  9   24761       employerc


Welcome to SO. Please make your data reproducible by using dput() to share it. Also, what have you tried? Share your code or any error messages.

Seems like what you are looking for is personc <- df |> dplyr::filter(mpi == "personc") |> head(4)

Your example data seems to leave too much room for shortcuts, but cumsum() and consecutive_id() / rle() can be handy in such cases:
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(
    m   = cumsum(result == "mover"),
    cid = consecutive_id(mpi, m)
  ) |> 
  add_count(cid) |> 
  filter(n >= 5) |> 
  slice_head(n = 5, by = cid)
#>       mpi result obs wages0  employer m cid n
#> 1 personc  mover   5  15000 employerc 1   3 6
#> 2 personc stayer   6  12923 employerc 1   3 6
#> 3 personc stayer   7  26269 employerc 1   3 6
#> 4 personc stayer   8  28538 employerc 1   3 6
#> 5 personc stayer   9  24761 employerc 1   3 6

Before filter and slice:
#>        mpi result obs wages0  employer m cid n
#> 1  persona stayer   5   9153 employera 0   1 3
#> 2  persona stayer   6  10713 employera 0   1 3
#> 3  persona stayer   7   9895 employera 0   1 3
#> 4  personb stayer   8  11416 employerb 0   2 3
#> 5  personb stayer   0   5258 employerb 0   2 3
#> 6  personb stayer   1   4970 employerb 0   2 3
#> 7  personc  mover   5  15000 employerc 1   3 6
#> 8  personc stayer   6  12923 employerc 1   3 6
#> 9  personc stayer   7  26269 employerc 1   3 6
#> 10 personc stayer   8  28538 employerc 1   3 6
#> 11 personc stayer   9  24761 employerc 1   3 6
#> 12 personc stayer  10  25661 employerc 1   3 6

Example data:
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"mpi   result    obs wages0     employer
persona stayer  5   9153        employera
persona stayer  6   10713       employera
persona stayer  7   9895        employera
personb stayer  8   11416       employerb
personb stayer  0   5258        employerb
personb stayer  1   4970        employerb
personc mover   5   15000       employerc
personc stayer  6   12923       employerc
personc stayer  7   26269       employerc
personc stayer  8   28538       employerc
personc stayer  9   24761       employerc
personc stayer  10  25661       employerc")

